# Ignoring exception in command buy

Tags: discord.py

An error pops up when I do the buy command. This code comes from [The coding academy discord server](https://discord.gg/pe4gExQg) but they didn't seem to know how to help. This is for a currency bot. Here is my code followed by the error:

```
`mainshop = [{"name":"Knife","price":65,"description":"Mug people! Unlocks `mug`"},
            {"name":"Laptop","price":5000,"description":"Post some sweet memes on reddit! Unlocks `postmemes`"},
            {"name":"Gun","price":10000,"description":"Rob people and businesses! Unlocks `rob` and `mug`"}]


@client.command()
async def shop(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title = "Shop")

    for item in mainshop:
        name = item["name"]
        price = item["price"]
        desc = item["description"]
        em.add_field(name = name, value = f"${price} | {desc}")

    await ctx.send(embed = em)



@client.command()
async def buy(ctx,item,amount = 1):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    res = await buy_this(ctx.author,item,amount)

    if not res[0]:
        if res[1]==1:
            await ctx.send("That Object isn't there!")
            return
        if res[1]==2:
            await ctx.send(f"You don't have enough money in your wallet to buy {amount} {item}")
            return


    await ctx.send(f"You just bought {amount} {item}")


@client.command()
async def inventory(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    try:
        bag = users[str(user.id)]["bag"]
    except:
        bag = []


    em = discord.Embed(title = "Inventory")
    for item in bag:
        name = item["item"]
        amount = item["amount"]

        em.add_field(name = name, value = amount)    

    await ctx.send(embed = em)    

async def buy_this(user,item_name,amount):
    item_name = item_name.lower()
    name_ = None
    for item in mainshop:
        name = item["name"].lower()
        if name == item_name:
            name_ = name
            price = item["price"]
            break

    if name_ == None:
        return [False,1]

    cost = price*amount

    users = await get_bank_data()

    bal = await update_bank(user)

    if bal[0]<cost:
        return [False,2]


    try:
        index = 0
        t = None
        for thing in users[str(user.id)]["bag"]:
            n = thing["item"]
            if n == item_name:
                old_amt = thing["amount"]
                new_amt = old_amt + amount
                users[str(user.id)]["bag"][index]["amount"] = new_amt
                t = 1
                break
            index+=1 
        if t == None:
            obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
            users[str(user.id)]["bag"].append(obj)
    except:
        obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
        users[str(user.id)]["bag"] = [obj]        

    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    await update_bank(user,cost*-1,"wallet")

    return [True,"Worked"]
```

**Error:**

```
Ignoring exception in command buy: Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "main.py", line 50, in buy
    res = await buy_this(ctx.author,item,amount)   File "main.py", line 104, in buy_this
    if bal[0]<cost: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)   File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I see your value of the variable `bal` is somehow a bool value due to which if you try to take out values from it as a list, it gives you the following error.

You should try checking the definition of the update_bank() command and check it's return type.

Check this website for more info on the error : https://www.tutorialexample.com/fix-typeerror-bool-object-is-not-subscriptable-in-python-python-tutorial/